# JavaEE7 Tutorial Websocket dukeetf2, socket remains open after browser tab closed

Tags: java, websocket, osx-mavericks, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

In the JavaEE7 tutorial dukeetf2 websocket example:

Why does the server keep sending the messages after the browser tab on the client is closed? Why is the ETFEndpoint @OnClose never called? I understand that the timer service keeps hitting send every second, but the connection should be closed surely, and its session removed from the queue? After which the queue should be empty?

I am using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)
OSX 10.9.1

Comment: The websocketbot application also does the same, it does not close the connections, from both Chrome and Safari, neither closing the tabs nor the browser works...

Comment: can you please try more recent Glassfish build? (http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/glassfish-4.0.1-b04-01_20_2014-ml.zip this one for example)